# CSS underline animation causes flicker in safari, found solution but caused blurry text

Tags: html, css, safari

As stated, only in safari, my CSS underline animation causes the rest of the nav bar to the right of hover to flicker. Putting `-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);` in the header section solves flicker, but makes text all blurry. Any solution to the blur? Below is CSS and HTML text that should be able to re build the issue

```css
header {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0 0 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 1280px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: #EBE8E8;
}

nav a {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'arimo', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

nav a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

nav a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

nav {
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
  background-color: #1764b0;
}

nav a {
  padding: 25px 30px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="/test/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav><a href="#">HOME</a><a href="#rworld">R-WORLD</a><a href="#lineup">LINEUP</a><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: ok will update quickly

Answer (score 0):

Well you're `<body>` tag is placed above your `<head>` tag, so I guess that would be your issue. Also in the future, you're best working within [codepen](http://codepen.com) for this type of thing. I've gone ahead and added your code to an anonymous pen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NyMOwd

Comment: it was a typo when adding code. I've updated it, and didn't have any affect on my problem

Comment: There is no flicker, open the codepen in safari and see. You're overthinking this, such simple logic does not require such extravagant code. I'd recommend you `position:absolute; left:0; right:0; width:100%` the `<header>` and see how this goes.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eVrPwQ there is in safari. I updated more than just the head tag, here is new code in codepen

Comment: webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0); fixed flickering in my actual HTML file but caused blur. but it looks like its not fixing the flickering in this test HTML

Comment: lol I swear its there. Are you in safari?? what version? I'm in Version 11.0.3 on macOS Sierra

Comment: ok the flickering and blur stopped on my actual HTML so I guess I am tripping. The code pen flickering is definitely still there though, but doesn't matter anymore I suppose. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wyjQqm

```
nav > a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: .25s linear;
}
nav > a:hover:before,
nav > a:focus:before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the translate prop from the header and add the following props to nav a::before

**backface-visibility: hidden;**

**font-smoothing: antialiased;**

Hope this helps.